# Get data from list of API response

Tags: python, binance

```
price_list = [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'lastPrice': '0.03574700'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'lastPrice': '57621.08000000'}]

print(price_list[1]['lastPrice']) # index = 1 for BTCUSDT, print 57621.08000000 => OK.
```

I need to get lastPrice for BTCUSDT.
Currently I can get it by index.
However, is it possible to get it by referring symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you only have two keys which equate to `identifier` and `value`.

You could create a `dict` and flatten your `price_list` into a key value pair of `symbol`: `lastPrice` making it much easier to access the price you need via `dict[symbol]`

```
data = {k['symbol']: float(k['lastPrice']) for k in price_list}

data
#{'ETHBTC': 0.035747, 'BTCUSDT': 57621.08}

data['BTCUSDT']
#57621.08
```